# Getting OpenSSL aes output in hex format

Tags: openssl

I am trying to use openssl's aes implementation. The encryption and decryption is working fine but when I compare the ciphertext to an online implementation they don't match.

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -e -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in plain.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

plain.txt:

```
0xf34481ec3cc627bacd5dc3fb08f273e6
```

encrypted.txt:

```
wrTS5lZ9x6qbwhLcgOffiLA5I25M1HBy81jjcg9SyAW2aCMcYElmaWW7fV9dBiwY
```

Online AES:
[image]

OpenSSL output is in base64 encoded format (because of the -a flag). How do I get it in hex format? 
(-hex flag is not there for AES)

**EDIT**: 
Even after using hexdump as suggested by muru, the encrypted text is not the same as online-domain-tools.com (see screenshot). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Vice Versa, I tested your encrypted-text to get back plain-text. From base64 to hex, and then converted using the key and iv you provide. The plaintext get back is not as same as the one you define here. Please make sure that iv and key are correct ones. I check other ciphers and plaintext with key and iv I have. The online tool provides correct ones. Thanks.

Comment: **** Your plaintext format is Hexadecimal. Base64 encoding is a standard method for converting 8-bit binary information into a limited subset of ASCII characters for safe transport through e-mail systems, and other systems that are not 8-bit safe. With OpenSSL, it is very easy to encode and decode Base64 data.

Answer (score 1):

- The online calculator that you are using is for 128-bits and you were getting a 256-bits encryption from Openssl.
- The file for the plaintext have to be in binary; not hexadecimal.

To change the file; an easy way to do it in Mac is by using "Hex Friend"; the file will look like something like this: "ÛDÅÏ<∆'∫Õ]√˚ÚsÊ". Once you have the file, use this command:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in plain.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

Then to double check your answer:

```
xxd encrypted.txt
```

If you are really interested in the AES implementation, check this website: [AES encryption](http://www.cronos.est.pr/AESencrypt.php)

This is the screenshot: [just look at the first line of the file!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTMFG.png)